# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime' when inserting into Database using EFW and ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am working on this `ASP.NET Core MVC` project where I am trying to save the values from `form` into `Database` when I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I have set `FromDate` and `ToDate` as `nullable` using `?` in the following way in the `ViewModel:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ILViewModel
{
    ...
    ...
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

In `Controller - POST Method`, I am adding values to the `Database` in the following manner:

**Controller:**

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
    historyObj.FromDate = locationsHistoryVM.FromDate;
    historyObj.ToDate = locationsHistoryVM.ToDate;
}
```

What to do?

Comment: Add `.Value` to get the `DateTime` - `historyObj.FromDate = locationsHistoryVM.FromDate.Value;`

Comment: @RandRandom. Can you post an answer so that I can mark it as correct answer? Others can  benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get value from nullable object. then you wont get error

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
    historyObj.FromDate = locationsHistoryVM.FromDate.Value;
    historyObj.ToDate = locationsHistoryVM.ToDate.Value;
}
```

Comment: I would make sure the ViewModel properties are marked `[Required]` too so the ModelState will be invalid if they are null.